# Add new port forwarding entry (TCP) on iMac

Tags: port-forwarding, tcp, imac

I'm on an iMac, Leopard OSX, and I need to add a new port forwarding entry (TCP protocol) in the iMac itself, since I have no router/modem connected to the iMac, I have Fiber, a network cable from the iMac to the wall directly. So how can this be done in the iMac?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

OS X Leopard uses a "Personal Application Firewall", so you cannot use the GUI tools in System Preferences to configure port forwarding. However OS X still includes a traditional port-based firewall ipfw which can be configured from the command line. Open a Terminal window and try "sudo ipfw add fwd 192.168.1.1,25 tcp from any to 192.168.1.2 25 in". Replace 192.168.1.1,25 with the external IP/port numbers and 192.168.1.2 25 with the internal IP/port that you want